# How do I filter a view within a view based on an Enity Reference field when NID is not in the URL of the container view's page?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have 2 content types: Artist & Artwork

Artwork contains an *Entity reference* field pointing to a single Artist called "Artist"

I have 2 views:

1. **Artist Detail** - A page view showing a single artist using title (artist's name) as contextual filter so url is human readable. eg. myexhibit/pablo-picasso
2. **All artwork by an artist** - A block view listing art by a specific artist using the "Artist" Entity reference field as contextual filter

I want to embed view #2 into the header of view #1 so that art tied to that artist appears on the Artist Detail page view.

I can get it to work if I change my filter on #1 to filter by Node ID and then pass that Contextual Filter to the embedded view. But I don't really want my URL to be myexhibit/213.

Is there a way to pass the node ID of the node matching the argument "pablo-picasso" to the embedded view?
Or a way to get the embedded view's contextual filter to work using a node *title* rather than the *NID* referenced in the Entity Reference field?

Comment: By which way did you create _Artist Detail_ page?

Comment: It's a page view. Basically display Artist content type only showing the Artist whose "title" appears as an argument in the url. So myexhbit/pablo-picasso shows only the Artist node titled "Pablo Picasso". I am using a view to accomplish this rather than just a default "Artist" page because I want only certain artists tied to a specific exhibition to have artist detail pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *myexhibit/NID* url for this view page and then set up an alias (for example *myexhibit/TITLE*). If you want to make this page only for certain artists you can filter them by node ID.

Comment: Thanks. This would work, but creating many aliases is more effort for my client than than it would be worth to maintain human-reabable URLs.

Comment: I think pathauto module can help you.

Comment: Pathauto solution works but is a heavy-handed way to do something that I know has to have a more automated solution. My guess is that the answer lies somewhere in the PHP Validation of the contextual filter. Something along the lines of "If $argument is not a number, get node by title (the title being the argument), pass _that_ node's NID as the argument to the sub-views"

Answer (score 0):

The embedded view doesn't work with node title argument because it's a title of parent node (*Artist*). To get it working you should add relation to the *Artist* node type and specify it in argument settings.

Comment: Sounds logically, yet it doesn't work as it supposed to be. I guess it needs more than that, PHP code validation I'm afraid - no out of the box solution.